# How do I create an object from another class (BlueJ)

Tags: java

I am making a program that simulates a Store and a Member. I am trying to write a method, memberRegister2(). This method is the the Store class but calls the constructor from the Member class to make a member object. This method is to be passed the name, id and pinNumber as parameters and then creates the Member object, which is to be stored in a local variable 'member'. I have no idea how to do this. As you will see from the code below I have tried to use the 'Member member = new Member()' But i do not know how to make the parameters user input.
(P.S I am using BlueJ)
Here is my code for both classes hopefully making my question make more sense. I am very new to java so excuse bad coding.

```
public class Store
{
    // instance variables
    private String storeName;
    private int total;

//Member member;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Store
 */
public Store(String newStoreName, int newTotal)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    storeName = newStoreName;
    total = newTotal;

}

//Accessor Methods
public String getStoreName()
{
    return storeName;
}

public int getTotal()
{
    return total;
}

public void memberRegister1(Member newMember)
{
    System.out.println("Salford Thrifty " + storeName + ": Welcome " + newMember.getName() + " (id:" + newMember.getId() + ")" );

}

public void memberRegister2()
{
    //Member member = new member(memberName, memberId, memberPinNumber);


}
//Mutator Methods
public void newStoreName(String newName)
{
    storeName = newName;
}

public void newTotal(int newTotal)
{
    total = newTotal;
}
}
```

and the Member class

```
public class Member
{
    // instance variables 
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String pinNumber;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Member
     */
    public Member(String memberName, String memberId, String memberPinNumber)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        name = memberName;
        id = memberId;
        pinNumber = memberPinNumber;
    }

    public Member()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        name = "Bob";
        id = "ASD123";
        pinNumber = "5678";
    }

    //Accessor Methods
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPinNumber()
    {
        return pinNumber;
    }

    //Mutator Methods
    public void newName(String newMemberName)
    {
        name = newMemberName;
    }

    public void newId(String newMemberId)
    {
        name = newMemberId;
    }

    public void newPinNumber(String newMemberPinNumber)
    {
        name = newMemberPinNumber;
    }
}
```

I have been told to keep the variable at the top private and use pointers? Not sure what this means but it has not been explained to me very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can a `Scanner` to read the user's input like so.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = s.nextLine();
```

Then just initialize your member instance using the strings entered by the user.

```
String memberName, memberId, memberPin;

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a name");
memberName = s.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter an id");
memberId = s.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter a pin");
memberPin = s.nextLine();

Member m = new Member(memberName, memberId, memberPin);
```

Also, you probably want to make pin, and maybe the id ints instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I have from an old class that should show you how:

```
SavingsAccount myAccount = new SavingsAccount(200, 5);
```

So when you want to create an object from another class you have to use that second class to initialize it as shown above the `SavingsAccount` is like `int` it instantiates the object and then the two integers `SavingsAccount(200, 5);` is used because the method within the second class is instantiated with two integers of its own so the object you are creating must have two integers of its own. And what I mean by the method has two integer instantiated is as shown in the code below:

```
public SavingsAccount(double amount, double rate)
  {
    super(amount);
    interestRate = rate;
  }
```

if you do not instantiate a method with two objects within the parentheses then you do not need them within:

> `SavingsAccount myAccount = new SavingsAccount(200, 5);`

I hope this helps any with your question i'm fairly new myself and am trying to help with as much as I can My course uses BlueJ as well and I know a good bit about BlueJ so I hope this helps.